# Why does this code cause Node.js using the phantom module to hang

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

If I change this:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    return ph.createPage(function(page) {
        return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
            console.log("opened google? ", status);
            return page.evaluate((function() {
                return document.title;
            }), function(result) {
                console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                return ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

to this:

```
 var phantom = require('phantom');
    phantom.create(function(ph) {
        return ph.createPage(function(page) {
            return page.open("http://www.google.com", function(status) {
                console.log("opened google? ", status);
                return page.get('title',(function(title) {
                    return title;
                }), function(result) {
                    console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                    return ph.exit();
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Node hangs at the console after printing 'opened google? success'and there is no further output.

I am trying to use page.get() instead of page.evaluate as described in the phantom module [docs](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node):

> Properties can't be get/set directly, instead use p.get('version',
>   callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misuse `page.get()`. This method has only two arguments, not three.

Here's how to it:

```
page.get('title', function(title) {
  console.log('Page title is ' + title);
  return ph.exit();
});
```